# How can I log into a Domain controller that doesn't trust itself

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, kerberos

I have a windows 2008 R2 standalone Domain Controller that I restored from backup.  The original DC is offline.

When I log in with valid user credentials I get the error:

> "The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship"

How can I log into the domain controller and fix whatever is broken?  This is the only DC in the Forest.

For what it's worth, I'm hosting this server at Rackspace, so my physical options are limited.

Comment: Can you log on with your local administrator account?  Also, was this stand alone DC the same as the original DC?

Comment: It is the same as the original DC.  The original administrator account was renamed and disabled per security guidance.  There is no local admin account (it's a DC)

Comment: You might have to use Active Directory Restore Mode to fix your OS, which may require a local logon.

Comment: @ponsfonze There are no local accounts on Domain Controllers.

Comment: this is your real problem: "This is the only DC in the Forest." once you get through your current problem, fix this one. ALWAYS have at least 2 DC's.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Active Directory Restore Mode is the only way, and it will require that you know the Directory Services Restore Mode administrator account password.

Incidentally, it looks like this problem was caused by improperly restoring a Domain Controller.  Just doing a standard restore from backup will leave you with a non-functioning domain Controller every time.  Next time, [follow the technet guide here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772519%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 10):

You can [restart into Directory Service Restore Mode remotely](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779687%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and log in using the DSRM (local administrator) password.

If you do not know that password, you can reset it by booting your virtual machine from an [ntpasswd](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) image.